# Problems using Ionic Native API and Javascript API in same app?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an app using Google Maps that makes use of BOTH the Ionic Native Google Maps API and the JavaScript version. Of course, the Native API is used on one page called `home.ts`, and the Javascript API on a sub page called `details.ts` which is reached by tapping on the infoWindow for a marker.

So far, this setup actually appears to work for me - but apparently I need to import "*GoogleMaps*" from `@ionic-native/google-maps` into *both* `details.ts` and `home.ts` for the map images to load on the main page - the markers and everything else will work fine.

Unfortunately, I *need* both APIs because Ionic Native does not yet support the use of the Google Places API. However, this seems to have led to at least one nasty issue so far -

On iOS, the app has a random chance of crashing/freezing when doing any sort of transition event, whether changing from page to another (the usual cause) or even just panning inside the map generated by `details.ts`. In XCode, when the crash occurs, the error I see in the console is something like this:

`*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]`

Of course, the number in objects[2] can be any number, as far as I can tell.

I haven't seen anything like this in the Android version of this app yet, but I have a hunch that it's there. I talked to someone who thinks that the app randomly attempts to use the wrong API, but I was hoping someone could provide a little more insight, and perhaps any other things that COULD go wrong with such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

when you are working with ionic and google maps app most of cordova plugins have issues recommenced to follow google maps js docs or follow https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/